# Operations on seconds on a Timelist

Tags: python, list, time

I'm working on a time list in the format %H:%M:%S.f:

['13:48:25.195',
 '13:48:25.994',
 '13:48:26.995',
 '13:48:27.995',
 '13:48:28.995',
 '13:48:29.995',
 '13:48:30.995',
 '13:48:31.995',
 '13:48:32.995',
 '13:48:33.995',
 '13:48:35.001',
 '13:48:35.995',
 '13:48:36.995',
 '13:48:37.995',
 '13:48:38.995',
 '13:48:39.995',
 '13:48:40.995',
 '13:48:41.995',
 '13:48:42.995',
 '13:48:43.995',
 '13:48:44.995',
 '13:48:45.995',
 '13:48:46.995',
 '13:48:47.995',
 '13:48:48.995',
 '13:48:49.995',
 '13:48:50.995',
 '13:48:51.995',
 '13:48:52.995',
 '13:48:53.995',
 '13:48:54.995',
 '13:48:55.995',
 '13:48:56.995',
 '13:48:57.995',
 '13:48:58.995',
 '13:48:59.995']

After setting a function to locate every item in the list. I want for a ceratin timestamp locate the **t-1** and **t+1**, based on seconds.

Comment: Your timestamps seem to be separated by 1 second each, so once you got the index `n`of the item you need, why not simply take `lst[n-1]` and `lst[n+1]` ? Or do you need a more general solution for the case of arbitrary timestamps ?

Comment: Actually I need more general solution for the case of arbitrary timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def adjust(h,m,s):
    if s > 59: m, s = m+1, s-60
    if s <  0: m, s = m-1, s+60
    if m > 59: h, m = h+1, m-60
    if m <  0: h, m = h-1, m+60
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s) // old-style formating
  # return f"{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}"      // new-style formating (Python 3.6+)


for t in ('13:48:43.995', '13:59:59.295', '8:00:00'):
    h, m, s = [round(float(x)) for x in t.split(':')]
    nearest_sec = adjust(h, m, s)
    add_one_sec = adjust(h, m, s+1)
    sub_one_sec = adjust(h, m, s-1)
    print(nearest_sec, '-->', add_one_sec, sub_one_sec)
```

Here is the generated output:

```
13:48:44 --> 13:48:45 13:48:43
13:59:59 --> 14:00:00 13:59:58
08:00:00 --> 08:00:01 07:59:59
```

Note that result cannot cross midnight, as your timestamps do not include days...